# Need to make a box over my title

Tags: titles

how to make a box over my title? Just a box (like that one on the picture) on my titlepage?

kind regards[image]

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: article :) and I know I have posted the last question, but their I asked for beautiful titlepages. Here I just ask for that box before my title :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by a simple `tabular` using the full text width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begingroup
  \bfseries
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \begin{tabular}{|*{2}{p{.5\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}}|}
    \hline
    Received: & Approved: \\
              & Date: \\
              & Signature: \\
    (for the instructor) & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}%
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

- Package `array` changes the calculation regarding rules. I have added it to get independent, whether it is loaded (because it is always loaded).

### Frame with `\fbox`

Similar, but with lines coming from `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\fbox{%
  \bfseries
  \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *{2}{p{.5\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}} @{}}
      Received: & Approved: \\
                & Date: \\
                & Signature: \\
      (for the instructor) & \\
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\medskip

\noindent
\fbox{%
  \bfseries
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{} *{2}{p{.5\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-2\tabcolsep\relax}} @{}}
    Received: & Approved: \\
              & Date: \\
              & Signature: \\
    (for the instructor) & \\
  \end{tabular}%
}
\end{document}
```

**Remark:**

- `\parbox` updates `\linewidth` to the current available width.

> [image: Result]

Comment: Do you really need to subtract `4\tabcolsep`? I think it is only `2\tabcolsep`, 1 right and 1 left of the content.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Thanks, I have fixed the second example. There `2\tabcolsep` are enough, because the other two are suppressed (`@{}`).